# Error when creating multiple N:1 relationships for an entity

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I am using the MetadataService to create 4 entities and create relationships between them.

The entities are: `TrexCalendar`, `TrexFrom`, `TrexTo`, `TrexAddress`

The relationships (all 1:Many) are:`TrexFrom - TrexAddress`, `TrexCalendar - TrexFrom`, `TrexTo - TrexAddress`, `TrexCalendar - TrexTo`

When I run my code the entities are all created successfully and the first, second and fourth relationships are created successfully.

Creating the third relationship fails with the following details:

> 0x80047007   Entity: new_trexaddress is parented to Entity with id:
>   7a6af338-bc23-e011-ad8c-9f5d300a22fe. Cannot create another parental
>   relation with Entity: new_trexto   Platform

7a6af338-bc23-e011-ad8c-9f5d300a22fe is the id for the `TrexFrom` entity.

So it looks like the SDK won't allow me to create a 1:N relationship between `TrexTo` and `TrexAddress` because a 1:N relationship exists between `TrexFrom` and `TrexAddress`.

What's weird is that I am able to create this relationship manually using the Dynamics web interface.

Any ideas what might be going on? How can I create both relationships programmatically?

I'm using the following code to create the relationships:

```
OneToManyMetadata relationship = new OneToManyMetadata
{
    ReferencedEntity = "new_trexto",
    ReferencingEntity = "new_trexaddress"
    SchemaName = "new_trexto_trexaddress",
    AssociatedMenuBehavior = new CrmAssociatedMenuBehavior { Value = AssociatedMenuBehavior.UseCollectionName },
    CascadeAssign = new CrmCascadeType { Value = CascadeType.NoCascade },
    CascadeDelete = new CrmCascadeType { Value = CascadeType.RemoveLink },
    CascadeMerge = new CrmCascadeType { Value = CascadeType.NoCascade },
    CascadeReparent = new CrmCascadeType { Value = CascadeType.NoCascade },
    CascadeShare = new CrmCascadeType { Value = CascadeType.UserOwned },
    CascadeUnshare = new CrmCascadeType { Value = CascadeType.NoCascade }
};

LookupAttributeMetadata lookup = new LookupAttributeMetadata
{
    SchemaName = lookupName,
    RequiredLevel = new CrmAttributeRequiredLevel(AttributeRequiredLevel.Recommended),
    DisplayName = CrmServiceUtility.CreateSingleLabel("TrexTo - TrexAddress", 1033)
};

CreateOneToManyRequest request = new CreateOneToManyRequest
{
    OneToManyRelationship = relationship,
    Lookup = lookup
};

try
{
    metadataService.Execute(request);
    Debug.Print("Relationship created successfully");
}
catch (System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException ex)
{
    Debug.Print(ex.Detail.InnerText);
}
```

Comment: I was able to get this to work by omitting the line of code that set any of the Cascade values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If both relationships are set as "Parental", you'll probably need to set one of them as "Referential"

Comment: Hi Mike. Thanks for the suggestion. Are relationships created as Parental by default? How would I go about setting one of them as a referential relationship? I've edited my question to include a code snippet. Am I doing something completely wrong?

Comment: The example from MS says to set all Cascade options to "Cascade" for parental. For referential, try setting Cascade None for Assign, Share, Unshare, and Reparent. Set to Cascade-Remove Link for Delete, and Cascade All for Merge. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc156290.aspx